# Minimizing flights between planets

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

This may be a peculiar question. I'm a completionist with my games, but I also hate wasting too much time in a play through hunting down power ups. In Metroid Prime 3, I try to avoid flying between planets any more than I have to, and while I'm on a planet, I try to pick up as much stuff in one trip as I can.

In Metroid Prime 3, what is the minimum number of flights in Samus' ship needed to complete the game?  Also, what is the minimum number of flights needed for 100% completion?

Comment: I couldn't tell you offhand, but aside from the story backtracks, but you will have to again at least 1 more time after you get the plasma beam.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of just completing the game, the number of cross-planet flights is **8**. This doesn't count flights before reaching Bryyo nor the flight to Phaaze.

- Start with completing Bryyo and moving to Elysia. (1)
- Must go to Bryyo with Plasma Beam to get Screw Attack to continue with Elysia. (2)
- Complete Elysia and go to Pirate Homeworld. (1)
- Must go to Elysia with Grapple Voltage to get Spider Ball to continue with Pirate Homeworld. (2)
- Complete Pirate Homeworld and go to Valhalla. (1)
- With pirate code, go to Pirate Homeworld to activate Leviathan. (1)

For 100%, the number of flights is **10**. Simply go to Norion and Bryyo once you're finished with the Pirate Homeworld and clean them out before going to the Valhalla. Remember to also clean out every planet as much as you can whenever you happen to be there.

Note that this count does not include the Elysia trip necessary to activate the pickup location data for the Pirate Homeworld. If so then that's another 2.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/928517-metroid-prime-3-corruption/faqs/50972)